# TypeError: doc.data is not a function

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Error message

```
TypeError: doc.data is not a function
```

Source code

```
state() {
 myWallet: ''
},

getters: {
    getMyWallet: state => state.myWallet.wallet,
},

mutations: {
    getMyWallet(state, doc) {
      state.myWallet = doc.data();
    }
},

actions: {
    async getMyWallet({ commit }) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        const uid = user.email;
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        const doc = db
          .collection('myData')
          .where('uid', '==', uid)
          .get()
        commit('getMyWallet', doc);
      });
    },
}
```

For the uid of .where ('uid','==', uid), the email address at the time of new registration is stored in the firestore as a value.

```
.collection('myData')
          .doc('Specific document ID')
          .get()
        commit('getMyWallet', doc);
```

If you specify a specific document ID without using where, you can get the corresponding document, but if you use the where clause, you will get an error message.

The cause is unknown.

> **Postscript**

↓SignUp.vue

```
methods: {
    async signUp() {
      await this.$store.dispatch('signUp', { username:this.username, email:this.email, password:this.password });
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        db.collection('myData').doc(user.uid).set({
          uid: user.uid,
          userName: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          myWallet: 300
        });
      this.$store.dispatch('getMyWallet', user.uid);
      this.$router.push('/home');
    }
  }
```

↓store.js

```
state() {
    myWallet: '',
},
getters: {
    getMyWallet: state => state.myWallet.myWallet,
},
mutations: {
    getMyWallet(state, doc) {
      state.myWallet = doc.data();
      console.log(doc.data())
    }
},
actions: {
    async getMyWallet({ commit }, uid) {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const doc = await db
        .collection('myData')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();
      commit('getMyWallet', doc);
    }
}
```

When I changed the code as described above, my balance was displayed when I newly registered and moved to the home screen, but there was only one problem.

For example, if you log out once and set'myWallet: 300'to 1000 yen and register again, the previous 300 yen will be displayed.
And when I checked with the firestore and the console, both were registered for 300 yen.
I don't know why it behaves like this.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `TypeError: doc.data is not a function` means that your object 'doc' is not of that type you think it should be. In the case when you use firebase it is just another object ... maybe a wrapper or can it be that 'where' returns a list of objects? Take a look at the documentaion of 'where' and what type of object it will return.

Nevertheless ...

```
.collection('myData')
  .where('uid', '==', uid)
  .get()
commit('getMyWallet', doc);

//-- This code returns another object than 'doc' where the 'data' function does not exist.
```

```
.collection('myData')
  .doc('Specific document ID')
  .get()
commit('getMyWallet', doc);

//-- This code returns the intended object where the 'data' function exists.
```

Comment: I implemented it without using where.
However, a new problem has arisen.
I added about that, so I would appreciate it if you could teach me ‍♂️